# The second example in Shafarevich's Basic Notions of Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, modules

In the first section of "Basic Notions of Algebra", Shafarevich used sets under mod 3 arithmetic to introduce the idea of coordinates and thus constructed finite number systems in order to coordinatise finite geometries, however I get lost after $I = (W,W) $, why is $AFH$ is given by $$VX + VY = U$$, and $DCH$ by $$VX + WY = V$$? It does not make sense for me, since the we can verify that $V+W = U$.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Using $0,1,2$ instead of $U,V,W$, the solution set of the equation $VX+VY = X+Y=0$ is $(X,Y) \in \{ (0,0), (1,2), (2,1)\}$, or $\{A, F, H\}$. Similarly, $X + 2Y = 1$ has solutions $(0,2), (1, 0), (2,1)$, or $C, D, H$.

Comment: Thank you for the hint, this is really smart. In fact Shafarevich gave similar hint but instead using 0, 1,-1. I still wonder how he or anyone found this.

Comment: Comments should only be used to **clarify**, not answer the question. See **[How do comments work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work)** for more information.